# How do I get the following regular expression to not allow blank e-mails?

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am using the following regular expression to validate e-mails, but it allows empty strings as well, how can I change it to prevent it:

```
^[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}){1,2}$
```

I am using an asp:RegularExpressionValidator.  My other option is to add on a asp:RequiredFieldValidator, but I am curious if this is possible to check for blanks in my RegularExpressionValidator, so I don't have to have 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: I have seen this site many times.  It is very good.  Thanks for the link again.  I found some good stuff on here.

Answer (score 1):

That expression does not match empty strings. The expression starts with `^[\w\.\-]+` this translates to "The string must start with a word character, period or slash. There can be more than one of these." There must be something else wrong or you copied the expression incorrectly.

Comment: Or the ASP bit is accepting empty strings despite the regex preventing them - I think I've seen something like that mentioned before.

Comment: There is your answer. "Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a RequiredFieldValidator  control in addition to the RegularExpressionValidator  control." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

Answer (score -1):

This RegEx validates if a given string is in a valid email-format or not:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]+\@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$/
```

Comment: When I put this into a asp:RegularExpressionValidator, it tells me it is not a valid Regular Expression.

Comment: Not really, some allowed characters (e.g. +) are missing

Comment: I'm new to regular expressions, so I have no idea how to read it.  I just found the one above from the web.

Comment: @Xaisoft: then it would be a good idea to add the information, that you need the RegEx for ASP. This is a Perl-RegEx. @Ofir: IMHO + isn't allowed in an email-adsress and I have never seen one up to now. But if so, we can add it as allowed character too :)

Comment: @Xaisoft: have you removed the "/" at the beginning and in the end of the RegEx?

Comment: The `+` character *is* valid!

Comment: @Erik:  I removed the "/" at the beginning and end, but it was still invalid for asp.net.  Did you edit the regular expression from your original post?

Comment: And you don't need to escape `_` or `.` in char class, or `@` at all, and this wont accept `user@history.museum` or `contact@airport.travel` etc

Comment: @Peter Boughton: Indeed - i found it in RFC2822. My fault. But it is unusual ;) @Xaisoft - no I did not edit. I would recommend you to use the RegEx from the site of Ofir.

Comment: It's not unusual. It's common enough that gmail explicitly supports it.

Comment: @Peter: well - unusual enough, so that I haven't seen in in the past 17 years :) But your right. It is defined and it is valid.